# C# Class with static methods creating base

Tags: c#, methods, static, factory

I am working on a stand alone C# SolidWorks API application which does parametric modeling. Many types/interfaces are required to access features of SW objects. An object of SketchLine type which is just a line in the sketch needs to be cast to SketchSegment type to access GetLength() method and it needs to be cast to Entity type to add attributes to it while to get it's persistent ID I need to use a method of an object of ModelDocExtension type etc... To ease modelling I expose methods related to SW object from different types/interfaces in my new class while the field with the reference to actual SW object lays in some ancestor class.

```
class GreatAncestor
{
    public GreatAncestor(SketchPoint swPoint)
}
```

```
class Ancestor: GreatAncestor
{
    public Ancestor(SketchPoint swPoint):
        base (skPoint)
}
```

```
class MySketchPoint : Ancestor
{
    public MySketchLine (SketchPoint swPoint):
        base (swPoint)
}
```

I have a Factory class with methods that return objects of my classes. It is pretty big class with many methods. Methods of Factory class look very much alike: they firstly create SolidWorks object and later pass it to my class:

```
class Factory
{
    public MySketchPoint CreateSketchPoint(double X, double Y)
    {
        SketchPoint swPoint SketchManager.CreatePoint(X, Y, 0);
        // CreatePoint is a SW API method

        MySketchPoint MyPoint = new MySketchPoint(swPoint);
        return MyPoint;
    }
}
```

I think it would be much neater to include static methods in my classes and not to use Factory class at all:

```
class MySketchPoint : Ancestor
{
    private static SketchPoint CreateSketchPoint(double X, double Y)
    // this method creates a point in the sketch in SolidWorks and returns it's reference

    public MySketchLine (double X, double Y):
        base (CreateSketchPoint(double X, double Y))
}
```

While writing modelling code:

```
MySketchPoint Point = new MySketchPoint(10,20);
```

vs

```
MySketchPoint Point = Factory.CreateMySketchPoint(10,20);
```

this design does not save me any coding lines but it allows me to have all related items in one place as well as one big class less. It does give me a static method in my classes which I do not like.

I would like to know drawbacks and applicability of this design.

Comment: Given that you don't have a coding problem per se, this may be better answered on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're creating your instances safely from within the factory methods, I can't see any immediate drawbacks without knowing more about the overall design of the application. It looks like a fairly typical implementation of the factory method pattern, which is very common and offers the benefit of encapsulating and organizing your creational logic.

The only thing I would caution against as a general principle is implementing something a certain way simply because you like the way the code looks one way vs. another. Have a reason for implementing it that way so you can explain why it's there if someone asks about it.

If you don't like having static members mixed in with your instance members, you could always put your static methods in a separate factory class to keep them separated.

Hope that helps to answer your question.